# Unable to find my.ini file to set variable event_scheduler = on

Tags: mysql

I'm using windows Os, mysql - v5.1.66.

The event scheduler does not seem to work after an restart of MYSQL server, After searching lot many forums, i learnt setting event_scheduler variable in my.ini file resolves the problem but, i searched a lot for the file in my system without any success.

Somebody help me please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find it in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5.
But it seems that there is no

Comment: i found some file called "my 2012-11-08 1258.ini" but i don't find anything as event_scheduler variable in this

Comment: in my file ,also no event_scheduler variable.

Comment: Just set up it by yourself?